# How to create/build local app with Phonegap CLI

Tags: cordova, command-line-interface, phonegap-build

I'm trying to develop a Phonegap Application(Android/IOS).

I've already created 1 private app in Phonegap Build. So now I'm getting an error saying

```
[phonegap] detecting Android SDK environment...
[phonegap] using the remote environment
[phonegap] compressing the app...
[phonegap] uploading the app...
[error] {"error":"Private app limit reached"}
```

How to create public app using Phonegap CLI.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

```
phonegap build android
```

or

```
cordova build android
```

For release build:

```
cordova build android --release
```

**[Deprecated]**

Here's the solution. It might help somebody else.

We don't have to create public app. Create an app and build it locally. In order to build the app locally using CLI, use the following command

```
>phonegap local build android
[phonegap] adding the Android platform...
[phonegap] compiling Android...
[phonegap] successfully compiled Android app
```

Comment: If you installed phonegap using NodeJS & Windows 7, you can find phonegap via **C:\Users\*\AppData\Roaming\npm\phonegap.cmd**

Comment: @rahmathullah i got this error"The provided path "/Users/*****/PhoneGapApplications/cardInfo/platforms/android" is not an Android project." please help me with this

Comment: @CharanGiri: you dont have to go to `platforms/android` path. just execute this command from ur project base folder. ie;  `"/Users/*****/PhoneGapApplications/cardInfo/`

Comment: @RahmathullahMPulikkal MAC01:cardInfo *****$ phonegap local build android
[phonegap] adding the Android platform...
   [error] An error occured during creation of android sub-project. 
/bin/sh: /Users/***/.cordova/lib/android/cordova/3.3.0/bin/create: No such file or directory

Comment: you have to configure `phonegap` path properly.

Answer (score 3):

The command `phonegap local <command>` has been DEPRECATED

Instead please try this command "cordova build android"

Answer (score 0):

Phonegap Build allows you to have 1 private app. In order to have more private app's, you would need to pay for a service plan. You can however have multiple public app's. To have a public app, you need to host your code in Github. Once it is there, you can create a public app [here](https://build.phonegap.com/apps) on the "open-source" tab.

Comment: Is it possible to do this using Phonegap CLI?

Comment: As far as I know, no. Because all your code is local, even if you try to have it built remotely, your code is still private.